# How to close an ActionMode menu programmatically on Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb, contextual-action-bar

In my application there is a ListFragment where each item from the list contains a checkbox. Whenever the user clicks on one of those checkboxes the app starts an ActionMode context menu.
But I want the application to close the ActionMode menu when clicking on another component.
I tried `Fragment#closeContextMenu()` without success.

Any ideas how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Whenever you are creating/starting ActionMode Create by

```
mMode = startActionMode(....);
```

To Dismiss it use following Syntax

```
if (mMode != null) 
 {
     mMode.finish();
 }
```

Comment: Isn't there a more 'local' approach to this problem? Something without  creating members?

Comment: Note: something that got me - mMode needs to be a class field of the activity (as the naming suggests) as you can't declare it AND use it in the same callback.

Answer (score 2):

```
actionMode.finish();
```

When finish method is called from actionmode ...it will destroy the action mode.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    //When action mode destroyed remove selected selections and set action mode to null


}
```

and destroy method is called from callback event

Answer (score 1):

*Kotlin code*

Use **ActionMode.Callback** to finish `ActionMode` after menu item pressed

```
 private val actionModeCallbacks = object : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
        mode.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_action_mode, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_item -> {
                mode.finish() // after click of menu item close action mode
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {


    }
}
```

**startSupportActionMode**

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallbacks)
```